# Print Access Across Parent-Child Domains

Tags: windows-10, network-printer, print-server, window-server-2019, windows-11

I am running a Parent/Child domain for a number reasons. I have a printer server that accessed the Parent domain on VLAN 2 and the Development domain on VLAN 3. The printers are on VLAN 2 and users on VLAN 2 print without a problem through the print server. For the printers users on VLAN 2 and VLAN 3 have "Print" permission. VLAN 3 computers are pushed the printers through GPO and like VLAN 2 print jobs are sent 2 the printer server to print out.

Issue we are having is when users on VLAN 3 print it shows up in their queue but the job says "Access Denied". I can't find out why they are getting access denied if they have print ability.

I can't find what permission they need. Any idea why they can't print?

Print Server is Windows Server 2019.
Clients are Windows 10 & Windows 11.

Comment: What security principal has been granted the permission(s)?

Comment: @GregAskew Domain level Local Administrator on the Parent Domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Our device control software did not have the permission on the print server to pass the print jobs. Gave it that permission and now it works!